# Creating a New Array in a Particular Order

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Once a particular promise is resolved, i wish to loop through each of the items in the response and push them into an array in a specific order.

1. `status-start`
2. `status-in-progress`
3. `status-completed`

How can I go about doing this? Here is my code so far:

```
dashService.getBatches(refresh)
.then(function (response) {
  if (response.error) {
    console.log("No data received");
  } else {
    angular.forEach(response.items, function (item) {
      if (item.status === 'start') {
        currentBatches.push(job);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Maybe it is more easier just to sort the result array? Or do you have a bit more complex use case?

Comment: @StanislavKvitash But the order that is mentioned is neither ascending or descending. How would you make sure the array is sorted in this custom order? Can't I push the items in specific order so that the array itself gets rearranged according to needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this

```
var newA=dataList.filter(x=>x.status=='status-start').concat(dataList.filter(x=>x.status=='status-in-progress')).concat(dataList.filter(x=>x.status=='status-completed'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you get your response, do the following:

```
    dataList = response.items;
    var currentBatches = [];

    var statusStartItems = dataList.filter(function(item){ return item.status === 'status-start';});
    //Loop through status-start items and push into currentbatches array
    statusStartItems.each(function(item){
      currentBatches.push(item);
    }

    var statusInItems = dataList.filter(function(item){ return item.status === 'status-in';});
    //Loop through status-in items and push into currentbatches array
    statusInItems .each(function(item){
      currentBatches.push(item);
    }
```

..so on

Comment: I don't think this is a better solution

Comment: This is just to give an idea/approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a map of available options and their corresponding order, then sort your values to insert based on that map. Then once sorted iterate the array pushing them into your destination array. That or you could concat them once sorted to produce a new array.

```
const orderMap = {
  'status-start': 0,
  'status-in-progress': 1,
  'status-completed': 2
};

newData.sort((a, b) => {
  return orderMap[a] - orderMap[b];
}).forEach(d => {
  originalData.push(d);
});
```

[Heres a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k0m2s1yt/1/)

Obviously you will need to change object structures etc, this is just a proof of concept. Also this is written in ES6, so no IE but it can be easily written in ES5.

---

EDIT: I see your sort is based on a sub property `status` updated the demo to reflect that.

https://jsfiddle.net/k0m2s1yt/2/

Comment: A map? A ``map``?

Comment: @Crowes i assume your referring to the fact im not using an ES6 `map` but a simple object? If not please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can also have 3 different arrays which could be concatenated into a result one:

```js
var dataList = [
  {id: 11, status: 'status-start'},
  {id: 2, status: 'status-completed'},
  {id: 3, status: 'status-in-progress'},
  {id: 4, status: 'status-start'},
  {id: 5, status: 'status-completed'},
  {id: 6, status: 'status-in-progress'},
  {id: 7, status: 'status-start'},
  {id: 8, status: 'status-start'},
  {id: 9, status: 'status-in-progress'},
  {id: 10, status: 'status-start'},
  {id: 11, status: 'status-completed'},
  {id: 1, status: 'status-completed'}
];

var currentBatches = [], 
currentStartedBatches = [], 
currentInProgressBatches = [{id: 200, status: 'status-in-progress'}], 
currentCompletedBatches = [{id: 12, status: 'status-completed'}, {id: 119, status: 'status-completed'}];

currentStartedBatches = currentStartedBatches.concat(dataList.filter(function(d){ return d.status ==='status-start' }));

currentInProgressBatches = currentInProgressBatches.concat(dataList.filter(function(d){ return d.status ==='status-in-progress' }));

currentCompletedBatches = currentCompletedBatches.concat(dataList.filter(function(d){ return d.status ==='status-completed' }));

currentBatches = currentBatches.concat(currentStartedBatches).concat(currentInProgressBatches).concat(currentCompletedBatches);

console.log(currentBatches);
```